# xslt apply-templates ignore one child type

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML in my XSLT.

```
 <section level="sect4" number-type="manual" num="(ii)">
        <title>
            Non-Hong Kong companies
            <footnote num="123">
                <para>The venerable statutory .</para>
            </footnote> with a place of business in Hong Kong
            <footnote num="124">
                <para>It may be noted in this context of English judgments.</para>
            </footnote>
        </title>
        <para>
            <phrase>3.039</phrase> Companies incorporal Companies,
            <footnote num="125">
                <para>Registration of the information specified in this
                 section must be effected</para>
            </footnote>
            of which three are relevant for present purposes:
        </para>
    </section>
```

here i want to apply-templates but ignore the footnotes, when i use the below.

```
    <xsl:template name="IndexItem">
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(@level,'sect1'))"><!--changed fron @num to sect2-->
        <xsl:variable name="tocpg">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#P',descendant::phrase[1])"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="nu">
        <xsl:number format="(i)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tocpgtag" select="translate($tocpg,'.', '-')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="current()/title/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Brac">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current()/@num,$nu)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="3"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current()/@num,'(')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('toc-item-',$ThisDocument//ntw:nums[@num=$Brac]/@word,'-level')"/>
</xsl:variable>
        <table class="{$d}">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="toc-item-num">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="toc-title">
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except child::footnote"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="toc-pg">
                        <a href="{$tocpgtag}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::phrase[1]"/><![CDATA[ ]]>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

the output is

```
Non-Hong Kong companies <sup>123</sup>  with a place of business in Hong Kong <sup>124</sup>
```

and when i use this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="./title[not(./footnote)]"/>
```

it is not displaying anything, the expected output is, just

```
Non-Hong Kong companies with a place of business in Hong Kong
```

and also if there are anymore other childs(like content style), they should be applied, only `footnote` is to be ignored.

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the `except` operator:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except child::footnote"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**

I am inferring that you are calling this template from the `section` node. Try this instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="title/node() except descendant::footnote"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Joel, thanks for response, i'm actually creating toc from all the xml data, here i've created a template just to get data, and when i tried `<xsl:apply-templates select="./title/node() except child::footnote"/>` the result is same, and when i did <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except child::footnote"/>, the rest of data in my XM is getting fetched, but i'm only trying for TOC, Thanks again

Comment: we could help better if you will post an input xml that has more information.

Comment: Joel is there a function that i can use like `except` only on `content-style/@font-style` ?

Comment: If this answer has been helpful. Click the check mark (just below the arrowheads to make it appear green). This way, other users can know that this is the right answer. Per your 2nd question, I think it is best to formulate another question.